# Modern vocab. "selfie", "troll" and "spam"

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

Do the following modern English words have Chinese equivelants that are understood by most young people:

- selfie
- troll / trolled
- spam
- phishing scam

Comment: In mainland China: selfie = 自拍, troll = 喷子, spam = 垃圾邮件. And for phishing scam, it is often specifically called 钓鱼网站 (phishing website).

Comment: @Stan thanks for these, very helpful. You may want to post as an answer?

Comment: @Growler No. I am waiting for a better answer, because it seems the words using in Taiwan are different. (And today is Mid-Autumn festival in China, I just want some relaxation :D)

Comment: @Stan Understood. Well I lived in Taiwan for 4 months and often heard similar translations there. But let's see what others post. And... 中秋节愉快 :D

Comment: @Stan I doubt if there will ever be an authentic answer that cover all (major) regional variations. If you feel shy on the length of the answer, don't be.

Comment: @NS.X. OK. Let me have a try.

Comment: How about photo bomb, meme, phablet, bitcoin?

Comment: @Steve very interesting. You should have put them in a new question. So far as I know: `photo bomb` there's no acknowledged corresponding Chinese word yet. Some literally translate it into `照片炸弹` (but I've seldom seen); some describe it with more details by pointing out what or who ruins the photo using `乱入` or `亮了`. `Meme`, no acknowledged corresponding Chinese word either, now using transliteration `媒母/米姆/谜米/弥母/迷因`. And for `phablet`, "平板手机"; for `bitcoin`, "比特币".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### [selfie](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/selfie) *n.* (also selfy, pl. selfies)

> **自拍** ***n./vi.*** (adj. 自拍的. Also specifically 自拍照片 (selfie photo) or 自拍视频 (selfie video))
>
> > - ***n.*** 这是他的自拍。
> > - ***vi.*** 他正在自拍。

### [troll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_%28Internet%29) *n.*

> **(Mainland China) 喷子** ***n.***
>
> **(Taiwan)** [白目 / 白爛 / 小白](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%99%BD%E7%9B%AE) ***n.***

Note: As the Internet slang is widespread, 喷子/白目/白爛/小白 are all acceptable in Chinese regions. However, the term [小白](http://baike.baidu.com/view/5500.htm) in mainland China now can mean 菜鸟 (newbie, green hand), for example

```
新来的小白，请大侠指教。
```

Then it's an almost neutral word.

### [spam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_%28electronic%29) *n.*

> **垃圾 + 邮件/短信/信息** ***n.***

The spam in English includes unsolicited bulk messages in all kinds of media. However in Chinese it's more specifically said 垃圾邮件 (and something else like that).

### [phishing scam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing) *n.*

> **钓鱼骗局** ***n.***

I checked some websites and found 钓鱼骗局 is used both in mainland and Taiwan for "phishing scam". However personally I don't meet the word 钓鱼骗局 much. More specific words like 钓鱼网站, 网络钓鱼 (Taiwanese 網路釣魚) appear more common. Anyway, the core word is `phishing (钓鱼)`, the derivatives are based on it.

Comment: From my experience, in mainland China, 小白 does not have the connotation of 'troll' at all. It means 'newbie' in a neutral tone or 'idiot' in a derogatory tone.

Comment: @NS.X. You're right, now it's seldom used in that way. But those from the old BBS age in mainland China might use it as "troll".